# Не могу понять как добавить в JComboBox дополнительное значение которое будет отображаться, если ничего не выбрано

Tags: java, combobox

Всем привет, хорошего дня!

Суть проблемы такая
Имеется БД, которая отображается в ComboBox

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А нужно чтобы было что-то типа этого

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Имеется rendere

```
class ComissionRenderer extends BasicComboBoxRenderer
```

{

```
public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value,
        int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus)
{
    super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected,
            cellHasFocus);

    String desc = "<Выберите комиссию>";
    if (value != null && value instanceof EHOTRUserComission)
    {
        EHOTRUserComission comission = (EHOTRUserComission) value;
        desc = comission.getUcoName();
    }
    return super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, desc, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);
}
```

}

как через него это сделать, если нужно уточнение пишите, я добавлю т.к. не знаю, что ещё добавить.
Спасибо!

Comment: Рендерер отвечает за отображение объекта в списке. Почему бы просто не добавить объект с описанием <выберете значение> в список?

Comment: @Z.John вот я чет не пойму как это сделать

Comment: Там где вы модель комбобокса заполняете списком перед этим вставьте в нулевой элемент ваше значение

Comment: @Z.John точно...спасибо!)
Блин, весь день думаю над этим, и вот всё было проще чем я думал!